# How to use webui-popover with dynamically generated table (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I have a table outputting some results to the screen in tabular form. For each table row, I have a column with an icon (more). What I want to achieve is that for each icon, on click, it shows a pop-over, similar to what Tidal does. But so far, it's only working for the last item in the list. I'm using [webui-popover](https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover) to get this done.

[image]

Here is what I've done so far. Please note that the CSS and JavaScript for webui-popover have been properly included in the project.

My HTML Markup for my rows:

```
<tr>
  <td>'.$name.'</td>
  <td>'.$title.'</td>
  <td>
    <a id="'.$id.'" class="more" data-id="'.$id.'" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My JavaScript for functionality:

```
var more = document.getElementsByClassName('more');
```

First I'm getting all items with the class `more`, and looping through them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < more.length; i++) {

   more[i].onclick = function(){
   var uid = this.dataset.id;

    // Popover
    $('#'+i).webuiPopover({
      url:'#pop-content',
      trigger:'click' ,
      style: 'v2',
      placement:'bottom-left',
      animation:'pop',
      width: '180'});
    }
 }
```

HTML for pop-over content:

```
<div id="pop-content">
  <a class="collection-item title">Signed in as</a>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <a href="#!" class="collection-item">Support</a>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <a href="#!" class="collection-item">Settings</a>
</div>
```

Straight out of the box, you can see that each row is supposed to show the pop-over upon clicking the "more" icon, but it's not doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because every pop-over is sharing the same content. You can fix it by adding:

```
cache: false
```

Besides that, you should setup the webuiPopover outside the 'onclick' listener. That listener seems completely redundant and could be removed, unless you're using the variable 'uid' somewhere else. I've created a working example based on your code:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/kr0shdx9/)